# What are the legal consequences for a tourist who runs out of gas on the Autobahn?

Tags: legal, germany, safety, driving, planning

There are many international travelers and tourists that enjoy driving cars on Germany's Autobahn every day, some of them would be unaware that running out of gas on the autobahn is illegal.

Although I have visited Germany twice and always traveled with trains and buses there, I just came to know after reading a few articles that parking a car on the Autobahn with an empty tank is illegal.

[image: Autobahn picture]

Question: What happens if a tourist runs out of gas on the Autobahn and isn't aware of German autobahn law? How to cope with this situation?

Can drivers finding themselves in this predicament be subject to fines? Is penalty the same for everyone regardless of nationality?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47006/discussion-on-question-by-ali-awan-what-are-the-legal-consequences-for-a-tourist).

Comment: As a curiosity, nobody has actually answered the question, which is about tourists.  Answer - ***YES*** this is totally illegal ***FOR TOURISTS***.  Exactly as for locals.

Comment: *Most* laws in *most* countries have the same penalty regardless of nationality.

Comment: @immibis you are correct in this, as well as individual city ordinances/laws apply to anyone passing through them unless said city decides to exempt them.  Here in San Antonio, Texas USA, we have an ordinance prohibiting use of a cell phone while operating a motor vehicle, unless you are using a hands free device, this includes a ban on texting while driving.  The ticket and Department of Public Safety fine applies to anyone passing through.  though it seems no one cares anyway as everyone keeps driving and talking and texting. ignorantia legis neminem excusat:  ignorance of law excuses no one

Comment: We are chinese and 2 years ago we run out of gas driving near Nuremberg. We were coming from Prague. It took us 30 minutes or more to get to petrol station. We walked and bought a can with gas and a nice old lady dropped us to our car. Nothing happened

Comment: @DaChun Of course when there are no officers around to fine you, there is now way for you to get a fine. But it still is illegal.

Comment: Runnig out of gas is also hard to do unintentionally. Modern cars can display estimated distance travelled with actual fuel ammount and road signs often displays the distance to the next petrol station. With sat-nav you can look for stations as well, and thus can plan your stops according your actual fuel level...

Comment: Is it legal to run out of gas on *any* highway around the world?

Comment: @JoeBlow surely I have answered this at the end of my answer

Comment: hi @Klettseb, no problem your footnote / my comment was a racetrack condition, good one mfg

Comment: @Crowley, I don't think _anyone_ runs out of gas intentionally. Would you? In many cars (such as mine), the low fuel light turns on and beeps once about 120 km before you run out of fuel. That's a long time to forget, especially when you're travelling through the middle of nowhere in the middle of the night—as happened to me not so long ago. I didn't run out of fuel, but I came pretty well close to.

Comment: @FighterJet You don't have "thirsty eye" glowing and blinking when the fuel is low and very low, respectively? It is (was?) very useful...

Comment: @Crowley: Nope. Beeps once and the light turns on and stays on until it runs out of fuel. And it's a German car, too.

Comment: It's technically illegal to do run out of petrol on a UK motorway as well, although I don't know that anyone has ever been fined or charged for it.

Comment: @immibis: In some countries, when breaking some rules that are usually punishable it's very common to be let off as an ignorant foreign visitor. Having the wrong ticket or losing your ticket for local trains in Japan springs to mind.

Comment: @JackAidley [citation needed] The Highway Code doesn't mention this, but rule 270 refers to the [Motorways Traffic (England & Wales) Regulations (1982)](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1982/1163/pdfs/uksi_19821163_en.pdf), which explicitly mentions running out of fuel as a legitimate reason for stopping on a motorway. (Of course, that doesn't necessarily mean it's legal; it may just be an acknowledgment of the reality that a car that's run out of fuel is going to stop pretty soon.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Rule 97 specifies that you should ensure your vehicle has enough fuel and I thought there was a specific rule about ensuring your vehicle was fit before entering a motorway under which it fell, but I cannot find any reference to it. I suspect, therefore, that either it has changed or I was wrong in the first place.

Comment: The The Highway Code has no legal standing in the UK, it is not the law.

Comment: @IanRingrose I'm aware of that. However, it does tend to say that you "**MUST**" (their emphasis) avoid things that are illegal, whereas it only says that you "should" (their lack of emphasis) avoid running out of fuel, "especially" on the motorway. Also, the Highway Code does cite legislation, and none of the legislation it cites for statements about stopping on the motorway mentions it being illegal to run out of fuel.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I don't know way “Driving without due care and attention”  is not used against people that not check the fuel level in the UK.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It is illegal to run out of gas on the Autobahn according to the German *StVO (Straßenverkehrsordnung)* which is the road traffic regulations in Germany. The fine can be from €30 up to €70 depending on the case.

The reason why it is illegal is that stopping on the highway due to insufficient petrol can be avoided and is a human error and therefore punishable.

Normally stopping on the highway in case of a breakdown has no fee but because this can be avoided and the driver has to make sure it does not happen it costs money.

It's worth mentioning that if you are a member of ADAC and call them (equivalent of AA, road service), and you are lucky and they get there before someone like the police gets there, they are able to sell you some petrol and you get out of it without a fine from the police.

It's under *§ 18 StVO (Autobahn und Kraftfahrstraße)*

German

> TBNR / FALL / STRAFE
>
> 118178 / Sie hielten auf der Autobahn/Kraftfahr­straße. / 30€
> 118704 / Sie parkten auf der Autobahn/Kraftfahr­straße. / 70€
> 118705 / Sie parkten auf der Autobahn/Kraftfahr­straße und gefährdeten dadurch Andere.    / 85€
> 118706 / Sie parkten auf der Autobahn/Kraftfahr­straße. Es kam zum Unfall.  / 105€

English

> TBNR / CASE / FINE
>
> 118178 / Stop (< 3 minutes) on the highway / €30
> 118704 / Parking (> 3 minutes) on the highway / €70
> 118705 / Parking (> 3 minutes) on the highway and putting others into danger / €85
> 118706 / Parking (> 3 minutes) on the highway with a following accident  / €105

Worth mentioning that there is no difference between tourists or locals in that case, meaning either one will be punished.

[Source](http://www.bussgeldkatalog.net/strassenverkehrsordnung/18-stvo/)

Comment: _Parken_ also mean you left your vehicle, where leaving means out of eyesight or more than iirc 17 meters away.

Comment: Good answer. There's no law that says "you cannot run out of fuel on the Autobahn". However, you are not allowed to park your vehicle on the Autobahn. Of course exceptions are being made for emergencies (driver/co-driver gets sick, or something like that), but if it can be avoided, you shouldn't stop or even park. And since it's so easy to check your fuel, it's avoidable and you will get fined if you run out of gas. Same is true for urban traffic: If you interfere with the traffic it is possible that you will get fined. "Interference" can also mean: Running out of gas so you have to stop/park.

Comment: @waka correct, i hope my answer clarifies this well enough.

Comment: I doubt the fact that "it's human error" makes it punishable. There are lots of avoidable errors that humans make that aren't punished. I suspect it's more about the fact that it's extremely dangerous stopping on the Autobahn, both to the occupants of the car and others who might crash into it at high speeds.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct ("the best kind of correct"), police, if they happen to come along at all, very often has better things to do than to fine you. My father got away with an overloaded camper trailer, out of gas, blocking traffic in the right lane in the middle of a lengthy autobahn construction site (so no shoulder, narrow lanes). Police pulled up behind him, secured the lane, helped him to partly unload the trunk to get to the canister, duly waited until he had everything back in and the petrol in the tank, and just wished him farewell when the car would start again.

Comment: Similarly a few acquaintances of mine (US tourists) ran out of gas on the Autobahn. Two of them walked the highway to the nearest gas station and  the other two waited in the car. I believe they got about half way there when an officer saw them, drove them to the station, got the gas, and drove them back to the car. The officer told them that they were lucky it hadn't been one of the mean officers that found them otherwise they would've fined them right then and there. It seems likely that it really depends on which officers find you and their mood.

Comment: I am not sure if this answer is correct. The expressions 'halten' and 'parken' (stop and park) are clearly defined in the German traffic law. A 'stop' is an intentional interruption of the ride not caused by traffical circumstances or command (VwV-StVO § 12) and 'parking' is defined as 'stopping' for more than 3 minutes or leaving the vehicle. If your vehicle ceases to move unintentionally you are not 'stopping' in the sence of the StVO. AFAIK, running out of gas on the autobahn is usually punished as a violation of § 23 StVO (failure to exercise due diligence).

Comment: @Berwyn: Doesn't that make it simply "it's human error with extremely dangerous consequences"?

Comment: I would hypothesize that even if the police do speak to you, your chance of getting a fine would be very low.  While running out of fuel is preventable, it is never done deliberately, and with no other offences they're probably not going to consider it enough for a fine.  No doubt they will always say "you're lucky it's not one of the mean police officers".

That said, I'd still try and prevent the situation in the first place.

Comment: As always with laws there will be many examples where someone "got away with it". That doesn't mean it's okay to do it.

Comment: @Berwyn: it's more that it being an unavoidable emergency makes it not punishable, I think.

Comment: I was just responding to "The reason why it is illegal is that stopping on the highway due to insufficient petrol can be avoided and is a human error and therefore punishable.". That isn't logical, to me at least.

Comment: @Berwyn It is illegal to stop at highways. There are some exceptions for emergencies/break downs, but getting out of gas is not considered any of these because it is easy to predict (read the gas gauge) and to prevent (refill or get out the highway because the gas runs out). The law does not punish you for the human error, it only says that this human error does not exempt you from the law. The same applies for Spain, BTW.

Comment: @SJuan76 "The reason that why it's illegal to murder someone is because it can be avoided and is a human error therefore punishable". Does that make sense to you? No. Me neither. The reason why something is illegal is rarely, if ever, due to being it avoidable.

Comment: @Berwyn As I pointed out in a previous comment, and also in my answer, the argumentation here is not correct anyway. The legal issue is that you according to German traffic law, as a driver, is obligated to make sure that the vehicle you are operating is in a suitable condition. That includes making sure that you have enough fuel. If you run out of fuel on the autobahn, you are not penalized for violating the 'no stopping allowed on the autobahn' restriction, but for driving a technically unfit vehicle.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: Running out of gas is certainly an *avoidable* emergency.

Comment: If I recall correctly, some methods of transportation are required to carry at least a certain amount of extra fuel with them (like a jerry-can) to avoid running out. Information on that might make a valuable addition to your answer.

Answer (score 50):

As Klettseb already wrote in his answer, you can actually get fined for running out of fuel in Germany, but his explanation of the legal basis and the list of expected fines are incorrect.

To avoid different interpretations of the colloquial terms 'halten' (stop) and 'parken' (park), the German traffic law uses narrow and precise definitions:

> Halten ist eine gewollte Fahrtunterbrechung, die nicht durch die
>   Verkehrslage oder eine Anordnung veranlaßt ist. VwV-StVO § 12 (1)
>
> Wer sein Fahrzeug verlässt oder länger als drei Minuten hält, der
>   parkt. StVO § 12 (2)

Translated to English:

> Stopping is an intentional interruption of the ride not caused by
>   traffic circumstances or command.
>
> Whoever leaves his vehicle or stops for more than 3 minutes is
>   parking.

As you can see, both terms are intentional actions. If your vehicle stops moving due to some unintentional circumstance, you are by the definition of the German traffic law neither 'stopping' nor 'parking'.

Running out of fuel is instead fined as a violation of StVO § 23. A vehicle operator is expected to make sure that the vehicle he is operating is in a suitable technical condition for the intended ride and running out of gas is considered a violation of this requirement. The regular fine is €25 (TBNR 123112), but it can be increased to €80 (TBNR 123600) if you substantially impair traffic safety or to €120 (TBNR 123601) if you cause an accident.

Comment: Running out of gas is unintentional if your car gives you warnings that you run low on gas?

Comment: @Klettseb Yes, running out of gas is not intentional. It might not be unexpected, but it is not necessarily intenional. In any case it does not matter, since the relevant question is if the 'Fahrtunterbrechung' is 'gewollt'.

Comment: Are there any known cases where the driver was punished for running out of fuel as a violation of StVO § 23? Or if you follow the normal emergency procedure - use emergency lane, emergency triangle, call the service, you'll be OK? Of course using service will cost you heavily...

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Google "benzin stvo § 23" and you will find plenty of discussions relating to real cases.

Comment: This answer is better (more accurate) than the one by Klettseb because it's about stopping, not parking. However, running out of gas _per se_ is not punishable. The vehicle must be "verkehrssicher", that is safe for traffic, not actually operative. It is however forbidden, and considered "endangering others" to stop on the Autobahn or on the side lane _for any reason_ other than (unforeseeable) breakdown, or because of a traffic jam -- you obviously have no choice in these cases. It is also illegal to set foot on an Autobahn, so going to get gas from the next station is "troublesome", too.

Comment: Note that breakdown is possibly punishable, too. If you are aware of impendent conditions that may affect the vehicle's correct operation, you are required to withdraw it from traffic immediately, using the shortest possible route. Which means that if e.g. the motor already makes strange noises, you aren't allowed to drive onto an Autobahn at all (since you may not stop there, and it is arguably to be anticipated that this may happen due to breakdown).

Comment: Running out of gas may not be intentional, but, because it can be prevented quite easily, can surely be considered as *(grossly) negligent*, and fined as such.

Comment: Excelt in rare circumstances. One of my cars once stopped with around 8l in the tank - 5l shown (yes, shown as l) and 3l "hidden reserve". Every time I tried to start the engine - the fuel counter was going down half a liter. What was going on was: no fuel, but the fuel meter got stuck. No joke.

Answer (score 9):

The questions from the OP are:

> 1. What happens if a tourist runs out of gas on the autobahn and not aware of German autobahn law, how to cope with this situation?
> 2. Drivers finding themselves in this predicament can be subject to fines?
> 3. Penalty is same for everyone regardless of nationality?

The key point in question is, naturally, the Latin phrase *ignorantia legis non excusat* — not knowing about a law does not excuse and does not prevent punishment (in German, the phrase is often cited ‘Unwissenheit schützt vor Strafe nicht’, which explicitly includes the punishment). This is also relevant to contraventions and most ‘illegal’ things relevant to drivers and driving are contraventions. § 11 of the [*Ordnungswidrigkeitsgesetz*](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/owig_1968/BJNR004810968.html) *(OWiG,* contravention law) reads:

> § 11 Irrtum
>
> 1. Wer bei Begehung einer Handlung einen Umstand nicht kennt, der zum gesetzlichen Tatbestand gehört, handelt nicht vorsätzlich. Die Möglichkeit der Ahndung wegen fahrlässigen Handelns bleibt unberührt.
> 2. Fehlt dem Täter bei Begehung der Handlung die Einsicht, etwas Unerlaubtes zu tun, namentlich weil er das Bestehen oder die Anwendbarkeit einer Rechtsvorschrift nicht kennt, so handelt er nicht vorwerfbar, wenn er diesen Irrtum nicht vermeiden konnte.

Loosely, this translates to:

> 1. Who at the time of infraction is not aware of a circumstance that belongs to the offense is not acting with intent. The possibility of penalties due to neglecting behaviour remains.
> 2. If at the time of infraction the offender does not realise they are doing something illegal because they did not know about the existence or applicability of a regulation, they cannot be penalised if they couldn’t avoid the error.

So which paragraphs actually apply? For one, there is § 18(8) of the [*Straßenverkehrsordnung*](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stvo_2013/BJNR036710013.html) *(StVO,* traffic code), which disallows stopping on motorways. This includes parking. There is also § 18(9) which forbids pedestrians entering the motorway. For these, the [*Bußgeldkatalog*](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bkatv_2013/BJNR049800013.html) (penalty catalog) defines the fines of €30 (stopping), €70 (parking) and €10 (entering as a pedestrian). Since these values are defined in annex 1, *(fahrlässig begangene Ordnungswidrigkeiten* — carelessly committed contraventions) § 11(1) of the OWiG does not apply.

§ 11(2) applies if you could not under reasonable circumstances have found out about the existence of such a law. However, that doesn’t apply at all. Since there was no exceptional haste involved in renting a car/travelling to Germany, you could have, under reasonable circumstances, found out about the rule that disallows you stopping on a motorway and leaving your car. You are expectet to read up on travel regulations before you enter a country. This is akin to being required to know that in Germany a red traffic light means ‘stop’ and not ‘stop, but if you want to make a right turn proceed cautiously’. So § 11(2) won’t help you, as many internet sources including [this one](https://www.welt.de/motor/news/article108882111/Ratgeber-Liegen-bleiben-ohne-Sprit.html) state. In theory, the fine applies.

In practice, the police often have better things to do than to check up on a car that is standing on the sideline. They have all reason to assume just a regular breakdown. Since you cannot evade a breakdown if it happens, you cannot be liable to pay a fine in that case. Thus, chances are high that you will get away with it. Unless of course the police see you refilling from your jerrycan — if they catch you doing that it is very likely that you are wrongdoing. Be prepared for questioning and a good excuse.

The best (and safest) strategy if you ran into the situation is to call a service car to tow you to the next petrol station (or off the motorway; whichever is quicker — note that an additional fine applies for not leaving the motorway at the earliest possible moment when towing). If one is just in sight, you can attempt to get away with walking over there, buying a 5 litre jerrycan and filling your car with that.

Naturally though, the prime strategy is not to run into the situation at all. Every petrol station on the motorway will be accompanied by a sign noting the distance to the next one, giving you enough time to decide whether you want to risk it. And of course, it is least hassle to just not run into the situation altogether.

The above text should have answered the first and second question. For the third, different fines for different nationalities would be a violation of the European anti-discrimination act if European nationalities are involved — this is the key point why the currently discussed road toll cannot be implemented in its current form. Regardless of European legislation, any differentiation according to nationality (except where something only applies to foreign nationals *per se)* would be considered discriminatory and likely not make it past the constitutional court. So yes, in theory all fines applicable are the same for everybody regardless of nationality.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: If the police officer on duty decided to report the offence, you would almost certainly be fined (and you would be a fool to contest it).

Comment: The interpretation of § 11 (2) at least is way off. In reality, it is about *not knowing the law* and whether that could or could not have been avoided. (In almost all cases, it is considered avoidable; people are generally required to read up on the rules beforehand.)

Comment: @chirlu Rereading the paragraph, I see that you are correct. I modified the corresponding parts of the answer and hope it is better now.

Comment: The service car you call will sell you some petrol. No need to tow your car. :-)

Answer (score 8):

The previous replied pointed out that motorists must take proper care of their vehicle to avoid hazards, which includes watching the fuel gauge.

That being said, the police are allowed to *prioritize* how they deal with minor infractions if there are too many to handle, and all German police forces have problems with accumulated overtime. So they *may* decide to ignore the infraction. Or they may not.

Comment: Regarding any police traffic action anywhere in the world: *the police may let you off*.  Sure.  The question is not even "is it legal".  The OP's actual question is: **This is illegal. Is it also illegal for foreigners?**  Answer - of course.

Comment: I think it would be useful to know that they frequently decide to ignore the infraction (and, perhaps, some idea of how frequently).  Just saying it is possible isn't really adding anything valuable.

Comment: @JoeBlow, I wanted to put the anecdotal reports into their legal context. I can't provide the statistics the other Joe asked for, mostly because there can be no firm count how often infractions are ignored.

Answer (score 5):

The basic assumption of the question seems to be that German (or any other) **law** distinguishes between tourists and other subjects.

I am not aware of any country with such a distinction.

Of course, the actual enforcement of a given law might differ for a tourist, but this does not happen at the level of the law.

Comment: The idea behind the question is probably that a tourist from a less developed nation, like Burkina Faso or India, where the road rules are quite different, may not be aware of this law. The question then becomes whether ignorance of a law may be an alleviating circumstance.

Comment: @Nzall `ignorance of a law may be an alleviating circumstance` Never, otherwise everybody would claim ignorance of the law (even German people "Maybe I knew that 20 years ago when I was preparing my driving licence exam, but I must have forgotten it because now I don't remember anything at all about that law, your honor.")

Comment: @SJuan76 As a citizen of a state, you are obviously assumed to know the laws of that state. However, if you're a tourist from a far off country (subsaharan Africa, Southeast Asia) where the laws are quite different, you may not know about the laws in Germany, and you may have a more lenient punishment because the laws in your country don't have a law like that.

Comment: Just for one example of a country that distinguishes, UK law distinguishes between residents and non-residents in laws related to motoring (although probably doesn't distinguish tourists from other non-residents). For one example of a distinction it makes, a non-resident can drive on a license from pretty much any country, whereas a resident has a 12-month grace period and then is required to pass the UK driving test and drive only on a UK license. A dull example of an administrative distinction, but there's no principle to prevent legislators writing laws that treat furriners differently.

Comment: That said, of course it would be rather strange to write one question on this site for every law in the world, asking whether or not that law applies to visitors as well as residents! The most common state of affairs is that it does.

Comment: Ignorance is not enough; it must also be unavoidable. And that is almost never the case, because people are expected to do research when necessary.

Comment: @Nzall That's not necessarily correct. If you travel to a foreign country, you are expected to know their laws.

Answer (score 5):

The penalty is the same for everybody, regardless of their nationality.

But in practice the decision on whether to *enforce* the penalty is up to the police officer at the scene. For a minor infraction like this, it really depends on their mood as much as anything else. Some police officers would tend to be more lenient towards foreigners; some might tend to be less lenient. As always, the best approach is to be polite and apologetic.

Anyway, what excuse could you give? "I wouldn't have run out of fuel if I'd known it was illegal"? That is not at all convincing!

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to address the possibility to run out of gas on the German Autobahn, since nobody seems to include this in their answers and most comments were deleted.

The chances of you running out of gas on german roads is **very** small. Just pay attention while driving and get gas early. Every gas station along the highways has a sign that says how long it will take before you will meet another gas station. This was you can determine wether or not you need to stop right now, or later on on the trip.

So in my opinion a good second question is; *'How likely is it I will run out of gas on the German Autobahn?'* and my answer to that is: Very unlikely, if you pay attention and don't wait until the very last moment to refuel.